# Create a column to insert value for every row

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query where I select the distinct values from a table that is loaded from a data file every day.  I do this because sometimes there can be a duplicate transaction in the file.  I am trying to select all distinct rows then add a new column and update with the current date for this distinct sub-table.  This way when somebody goes to pull from the distinct table they know the last day it was updated. I am just trying to insert a column called dedup_date and populate with the current_Date when the query is ran.  I thought of doing insert it but I need this populated for each row in the table and wasn't sure the correct syntax.

I was thinking of doing it as a case when

```
CASE WHEN account_number is NULL THEN current_date
else current_date end as last_updt_dt
```

Comment: You are adding current_date irrespective of account_number is null or not, so the case is irrelevant.Might as well just add current_date as last_updt_dt.

Comment: Thank you. I must have had my syntax wrong bc I was trying different versions of that and it would not work.